# I still don't get how IMUL works in Assembly

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, multiplication, twos-complement

I am a begginer with assembly i just started learning it and i don't get how the instruction IMUL really works

For example i'm working on this piece of code on visual studio:

---

```
Mat = 0A2A(hexadecimal)

__asm {

    MOV AX, Mat
    AND AL,7Ch
    OR AL,83h
    XOR BL,BL
    SUB BL,2
    IMUL BL
    MOV Ris5,AX
}
```

---

the result in Ris5 should be 00AA (in hexadecimal), for the first couple lines i'm all good, from the first line to 'SUB BL,2'
the results are AL = AB (AX =0AAB) 
but then starting from IMUL i'm stuck.
I know that IMUL executes a signed multiply of AL by a register or a byte or a word .. and stores the result in AX (here) but i can't find the same result (00AA)

Comment: You say the result *should be* `00AA`. What was it? The result is actually `AX = A9AA` which is `AB * FE`.

Comment: @WeatherVane are you sure: isn't IMUL with an 8 bit operand supposed to multiply just AL by that operand and then store the result in AX?

Comment: @Kaz the two operands are `AB` and `FE`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I banged this multiplication out into a tiny assembly program that I spun into an executable. The result in `ax` is indeed `00AA` as OP expects.

Comment: @Kaz yes. My first comment forgot it is signed. I ran a small assembly program too and hex `AB * FE` is decimal `-85 * -2` which is `170` which is `AA`. Tempted to think that is an overflow for 8-bit, although the product is 16 bits

Comment: @weathervane However, if I bang out the code exactly, then I get `FFB0` in `ax`.   Basically, in `imul bl`, the other operand is `ax`, not `al`.

Comment: @Kaz I since have entered the exact code (with `short` variables) which still gives `AA`. Note: the 8 bit `IMUL` operand is a multiplier for `AL` not `AX` on 8086 at least.

Comment: @Kaz please see [this](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_138.html). The operand is R8 not IMM8.

Comment: its a signed multiply not an unsigned. 0xFFAB * 0xFFFE not 0x00AB * 0x00FE.

Comment: @old_timer they are 8-bit operands, not 16, although you are right when extended to 16-bit values. However it is an 8-bit multiply with a 16-bit product and because `AH` in the product is not the sign-extension of `AL` the flags `O` and `C` will be set, indicating that `AA` has overflowed an 8-bit product. Which it has because decimal `170` won't fit a signed 8-bit value. My first comment at the top was incorrect - I had overlooked "signed".

Comment: @WeatherVane to get the math right you have to sign extend to 16 bit values, same as what the hardware does, in order to get the 16 bit result.  And when viewed that way we can get past the answer is 0x00AA tangent and focus on the question.

Comment: @old_timer if you extend the operands to 16 bits, you get a 32-bit product, but you don't.

Comment: @WeatherVane its obviously not a full 16x16 are you just nitpicking the language used here or not understanding?

Comment: if you want to get the right answer with your calculator 0xFFAB * 0xFFFE = 0xFFA900AA and keep the lower 16 bits 0x00AA.  if you want to get the wrong answer for a signed 8 bit multiply then 0x00AB * 0x00FE = 0x0000A9AA and keep the lower 16 bits 0xA9AA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MOV AX, Mat    AX = 0x0A2A  (...00101010)
AND AL,7Ch     AX = 0x0A28  (...00101000)
OR AL,83h      AX = 0x0AAB  (...10101011)
XOR BL,BL      BL = 0x00
SUB BL,2       BL = 0xFE
IMUL BL        AX = 0xFFAB * 0xFFFE = 0x00AA
MOV Ris5,AX    Ris5 = 0x00AA
```

When you multiply two N bit numbers the lower N bits don't care about signed vs unsigned, but as you pad the numbers then you get into signed vs unsigned multiply instructions as you will see in some instruction sets.  To not lose precision you desire a 2*N number of bits result, grade school math:

```
   00000000aaaaaaaa
*  00000000bbbbbbbb
=====================

   AAAAAAAAAAaaaaaa
*  BBBBBBBBBBbbbbbb
====================
```

Signed vs unsigned with the Capital letter representing the sign extension

0xAB = 171 unsigned = -85 signed

0xFE = 254 unsigned = -2 signed

unsigned multiply 171 * 254 = 43434 = 0xA9AA

signed multiply -85 * -2 = 170 = 0x00AA

The lower byte is the same as they are 8 bit operands and the sign extension doesn't come into play:

```
         bbbbbbbb *a[0]
        bbbbbbbb  *a[1]
       bbbbbbbb   *a[2]
      bbbbbbbb    *a[3]
     bbbbbbbb     *a[4]
    bbbbbbbb      *a[5]
   bbbbbbbb       *a[6]
+ bbbbbbbb        *a[7]
==================
 cyyyyyyyxxxxxxxx
```

If you look up the columns the x bits are not affected by the sign extension so are the same for unsigned and signed.  y bits are affected as well as the carry out of the msbit c which makes up the 16th bit of the result.

Now the tool is not complaining about this syntax, is it?

```
Mat = 0A2A(hexadecimal)
```

Without an h at the end or 0x or $ up-front that looks like octal, but the A's would cause an error if octal (or if decimal).  Assuming you start with 0x0A2A, I think your understanding is solid.

Comment: okay similar to grade school math.  with decimal we can use negative numbers easily.  in binary in a computer we cant just mess with a minus sign and do that separately from the values.  that is embedded in the values.   addition and subtraction (which in a computer uses addition logic) are sign independent thanks to twos complement, but multiply and divide are affected by signed vs unsigned interpretations of the bits.